# My CSS made with Tailwind doesn't work on build with gridsome for netlify

Tags: build, netlify, tailwind-css, gridsome

When I build (netflify build) my Gridsome personal website, tailwind CSS classes doesn't work and the website look's like without CSS.

I have already tried to build without git, reinstall tailwind...

I show my gridsome config if that's the problem:

```
const tailwind = require('tailwindcss');
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');

const postcssPlugins = [
  tailwind(),
]

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') postcssPlugins.push(purgecss());

module.exports = {
  siteName: 'Zolder | Works',
  plugins: [],
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: postcssPlugins,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Missing require for tailwind perhaps?

const tailwind = require('tailwindcss')

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well. I used the Tailwind Plugin for Gridsome and it worked locally but when deploying to Netlify, the Tailwind css wasn't getting added.

Referencing this starter file: https://github.com/drehimself/gridsome-portfolio-starter/blob/master/src/layouts/Default.vue

I added the `main.css` with all the Tailwind imports file to the end of the Default Layout template instead, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Tailwind to your Gridsome project with these steps:

- edit `gridsome.config.js`

```js
    module.exports = {
      siteName: "Zolder",
      plugins: [],
      chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
          .rule("postcss-loader")
          .test(/.css$/)
          .use(["tailwindcss", "autoprefixer"])
          .loader("postcss-loader");
      }
    };
```

- create a `global.css` file in `./src/styles`

  ```
  @tailwind base;

  @tailwind components;

  @tailwind utilities;
  ```
- import `global.css` in `main.js`

  `import './styles/global.css'`